# Why can't I have an inner structure when two files include each other?

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, dependencies, circular-dependency

For context, I'm writing an operating system:

I have a `struct vt_device_s` and a `struct __vt_device_s` which is architecture specific and lives inside of `vt_device_s` like so:

```c
struct
vt_device_s
{
    struct __vt_device_s __device;
    size_t cursor_x;
    size_t cursor_y;
};
```

Now for the architectural struct:

```c
struct
__vt_device_s
{
    uint16_t *memory;
    size_t memory_len;
};
```

The header `<dev/vt.h>` knows about `__vt_device_s` defined in `<sys/_vt.h>` because it is included, yet I get this error:

```
error: field '__device' has incomplete type
   48 |  struct __vt_device_s __device;
      |
```

I realise this is because both files rely on each other (the whole conflict is caused by `_vt.c` including `_vt.h` including `vt.h` including `_vt.h`) but I don't understand how it is a compile problem. I have include guards in both files!

PS: I understand this would be a non-issue if I used a pointer but as it's an operating system, this driver needs to function before paging is set up (that is, `malloc` and `free` don't exist yet).

Here are the three files in question:

**dev/vt.h**

```c
#ifndef _DEV_VT_H_
#define _DEV_VT_H_ 1

#include <stddef.h>

#include <sys/_vt.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

struct
vt_device_s
{
    struct __vt_device_s __device;
    size_t cursor_x;
    size_t cursor_y;
};

void vt_init(struct vt_device_s *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#endif /* _DEV_VT_H_ */
```

**sys/_vt.h**

```c
#ifndef _I386__VT_H_
#define _I386__VT_H_ 1

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <dev/vt.h>

#define __VT_WIDTH  80
#define __VT_HEIGHT 25
#define __VT_MEMOFF 0xb8000

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

struct
__vt_device_s
{
    uint16_t *memory;
    size_t memory_len;
};

void __vt_init(struct vt_device_s *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#endif /* _I386__VT_H_ */
```

**sys/_vt.c**

```c
#include <sys/_vt.h>

void
__vt_init(struct vt_device_s *device)
{
    device->__device.memory = (uint16_t *) __VT_MEMOFF;
    device->__device.memory_len = __VT_WIDTH * __VT_HEIGHT;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your double include guards prevent the one file from including itself when it is re-included by the other.  The only way to fix this is you have got to break the cycle.  Decide which header is "higher" and will include the "lower" and don't try to include the higher one from the lower one.  The lower one must be valid on its own.

The reason for this is that the pre-processor has to transform multiple files into one linear sequence of lines for the compiler.  The compiler has to see one set of file contents before the other.

If you have cyclic includes like this you make it up to the final user of the code which one comes first.  If they include file A, then it will include file B, which will try to include file A again but it will be prevented by the include guards, so the contents of B will be parsed first.  On the other hand if the final user includes B first, then the contents of A will be seen first by the compiler.

So if you leave it like it is, then it is effectively random which file gets included first.  If you break the cycle, you get to decide yourself which is included first.

Once you have decided, you can fix the compiler errors about incomplete types by making whichever file you choose to put first able to stand on its own and then letting the one that is second use definitions from the first.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem with my naming convention is given underscores is an established standard for internal functions that no users should ever see. Furthermore, my code is placed in the following directory tree: `sys/i386/_vga.h`. What you are seeing is the location after installation. Given the exact same stubs are located in `sys/amd64/_vga.h` and so on, this is a non issue. Regardless, it's a personal project, I'm not creating this for a client. As for your solution, I already knew this. I'm asking **why** it is an issue.

Comment: Hiding an identifier by starting it with an underscore is fine.  Deliberately creating multiple sets of nearly identical identifiers is horrific!

I will, edit my answer to further explain what is wrong with the includes, and we can keep discussion of naming convention in the comments :-).

Comment: If my word is not enough, perhaps you'll be interested to know that even projects such as FreeBSD use such naming conventions, namely [here](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/include/_ctype.h) for an example. `ctype.h` contains the stubs and `_ctype.h` is an implementation.

Comment: `Deliberately creating multiple sets of nearly identical identifiers is horrific!` I'm just following what I see. If you have a better suggestion, I'd be grateful to hear it. Structuring an OS is hard...

Comment: Now that you've edited, I'm understanding what you're saying but surely that has to be hack-y to perform a selection as to which file to include first?

Comment: I did make a suggestion.  Call one of them eg: generic_foo, and the other platform_foo.

Comment: It's not hacky at all.  Every project that I have ever worked on has had some files that depend on other files.  Any time there is a dependency the depender includes the dependee and the dependee doesn't include the depender.

Comment: Woops, you did. I suppose I'll go rename them to `vt_init` and `__i386_vt_init` or `__platform_vt_init` then.

Comment: "_the dependee doesn't include the depender_" - I'm not sure I follow. Both A relies on B and B on A. If I just stop including A in B I get `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` and `declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration`.

Comment: *I don't understand what your problem with my naming convention is given underscores is an established standard for internal functions that no users should ever see.*  Names starting with double underscores or an underscore and an upper-case letter are [reserved identifiers for the C implementation](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3), they're not for "internal functions that no users should ever see."

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm only conforming to POSIX.1 and c89/ANSI standards. (Interesting question, were they reserved back then as well?) I'm also the one implementing the C library so any reservations are entirely up to me. Also, why does FreeBSD use double underscores then? Are they breaking convention? I had no idea this was a thing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The OP did say he was writing an OS, that means they are reserved especially for him!

Comment: @user15215328 I can see that they depend on each other now, you need to change that.  For example the generic struct could have all its common fields at the start and then an array of longs that is big enough for the specific fields in the biggest imaginable arch specific struct.  It then doesn't have to include the specific header.  This is a bit like how struct sockaddr works.  It isn't very type safe.

The other way around you could make the generic struct a member of the specific one.

Comment: @TomV What I've done is make the implementation completely independent and run any generic code in the stub which is what I should have been doing in the first place instead of trying to send through the user-visible struct. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @user15215328 *I'm only conforming to POSIX.1 and c89/ANSI standards. (Interesting question, were they reserved back then as well?*  They were reserved per [**4.1.2 Standard headers**,](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.1.2) in  C89 (pedantically, the draft copy).  A C implementation can't really be separated entirely from the OS it's implemented on (or the OS from the compiler used to build it), but I suspect you're not also implementing your C environment from scratch, so you won't really have full rein to use any identifier you want.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I suppose then, that that is a risk I will take for the foreseeable future. I'm just having fun and given I don't use such syntax in the real world, I can think of it as giving my compiler the finger. :-) (PS: thanks for the draft, will be good to polish my standards)

Comment: @user15215328  LOL. Some compilers probably deserve that...